# JPA's bulk update works when changing the object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Normally, if I change an object mapped with @Entity, it will be persisted at the end of transactional methods, even if I don't call any save methods.

I'm doing a bulk update for performance reasons using the EntityManager#CriteriaUpdate from JPA, but I need to trigger some events in the setters of the objects, so I set them, but don't call the save method.

What I want to know is if the bulk update is useful if I change the object, or each object will be persisted, even though the bulk update is executed?

PgtoDAO:

```
public void bulkUpdateStatus(List<Long> pgtos, Long newStatusId) {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = this.manager.getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaUpdate<Pgto> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Pgto.class);
  Root e = update.from(Pgto.class);

  update.set("status", newStatusId);
  update.where(e.get("id").in(pgtos));

  this.manager.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();

}
```

PgtoService:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public int changePgtosStatus(List<Pgto> pgtos, StatusEnum newStatus){
  ...
  List<Long> pgtoIds = new ArrayList<Pgto>();
  for(Pgto pgto : pgtos){
    // Hibernate will persist each object here, individually?
    pgto.setStatus(newStatus.id());
    pgtoIds.add(pgto.getId());
  }

  pgtoDao.bulkUpdateStatus(pgtoIds, newStatus.id());

  // I tried setting a different status here to the objects, but it did not persisted

}
```

Perhaps I should end the connection after the bulk update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criteria query and changed entities are treated separately.   Criteria query is just executed, and managed (loaded  via entity manager) changed entities are synchronized with database on transaction commit. 
If you like to prevent this, you will have to detach those entities from entity manager. Then changes will be not propagated to database anymore

Comment: Can I detach the entity just on that method in the PgtoService? There are other methods that need the entity to be synchronized in this class

Comment: Once entity is detached,  it stays detached for this transaction - so boundary is not the class, but transaction/session  ( and in most situations thread, as it will be usually bound to it )